# Force Visual Studio to Rebuild a Solution before Publishing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a multi project solution in VS2102. One of the projects has a post-build event that updates version numbers in the main project (AssemblyInfo.cs and the project file) before compiling. This means that the whole solution must be rebuilt before clicking Publish Now (VS usually doesn't build at this point since there may not be any changes). Is there a way to program VS to automatically rebuild pre-publish?

Comment: I presume  you meant a pre-build event. Changing AssemblyInfo.cs after the build won't do much good.

Comment: What is the type of project that is being published?  Some will automatically build the current project and dependencies before publish.

Comment: It's actaully a post-build on one of the secondary projects. By the time a prebuild fires VS has already cached the main project file in memory and we had great trouble editing it